# how to pass Array as paramenter in VB macro

Tags: arrays, vb.net, macros, parameter-passing

I'm trying to pass an array parameter to a VB sub procedure. if I use '()' along with the array name then it says **'Sub or Function not defined'** and if it is removed , then it throws compiler error as "**Type mismatch**: Array or user defined type expected".

```
Dim arypred() As Long
Dim dependlink() As Long

Main Sub()

.....
getPred arypred(), dependlink() 'Call to the sub procedure getPred

End Sub

Public Sub getPred(arypred() As Long, dependlink() As Long)

....

End Sub
```

I googled, but I'm not able to track exact solution for this. Also, I'm confused between variant usage and Array() as most examples I saw were using Varaint.

Apologies if this ques is very basic; I'm new to VB and learning it..
please help to make this work..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it this way

```
Sub Main()
    Dim arypred() As Long = Nothing
    Dim dependlink() As Long = Nothing

    getPred(arypred, dependlink)
End Sub

Public Sub getPred(ByVal arypred() As Long, ByVal dependlink() As Long)


End Sub
```

You don't have to include the `()` symbol when passing the array and make sure to assign an initial value to the array as you declare. For a start, assign `nothing`.

**Suggestion:**
If you want to get a value after calling the `getPred` method, use `Public Function` instead to return a value. If the method is used within the class only then use `Private` instead of `Public` unless if it's a module. If you want both variables (arypred and dependlink) to return the new values after executing the `getPred` method, use `ByRef` instead of `ByVal`. For more info about ByRef and ByVal, [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddck1z30.aspx) and [here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13372/Functions-VS-Subroutines-and-By-Val-Vs-By-Ref-in-V)

Comment: thanks MAC. I tried the above solution, but it throws compiler error as "Array argument must be ByRef". I tried replacing ByVal with ByRef but then also it shows syntax error at calling line:                                    getPred(arypred, dependlink)

Comment: can you include all the significant codes?  @kousalyarajan 'cause the problem may lie with the other parts of your code.

Comment: Now it is working fine.. Problem was with the visibility of the array variables. I delcared them in a procedure, which calls procedure1 in which gePred is called.       Public Sub normal2D_Process(shp As Visio.Shape)     ...........     getPred arypred() , dependlink()   End Sub Public Sub getPred(ByRef arypred() As Long, ByRef dependlink() As Long)

Comment: @kousalyarajan i see. good luck with the rest of your coding! :)